# Change css two times by clicking two separate buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an interface that you can press edit to bring up borders and change the background color of other divs. The edit button gets replaced by cancel and save buttons. I want the borders and background to change on clicking edit and revert to normal on clicking save or cancel.

I am able to make the divs change when clicking edit, but I can't make them change back on clicking cancel or save. I'm using the exact same Jquery function for both.

```
//show lines on clicking edit
$(".editbutton").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".material_input").css("border-bottom", "1px solid #ccc").css("background-color", "#fafafa");
});

//hide lines on clicking save or cancel
$(".label-container button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".material_input").css("background-color", "#fff");
});
```

I know that my second one doesn't include the border. I'm just trying to get the background back to white first.

Edit: It looks like there's a problem with the second function accessing the DOM because I can do this easily in Codepen. If someone can help me straighten this out that'll be great.

Here's the DOM for the relevant classes:

.parent > .editbutton

.parent > .button-wrap > .label-container

.parent > .section > .fields > .material_input

Comment: if i understand correctly you want hide border-bottom, just add .css('border-bottom', 'none');

Comment: More a recommendation than answer, but - I'd suggest using `toggleClass` in jQuery to add/remove a class on the element when the button is clicked. Example: https://codepen.io/atwright147/pen/HEfDu

Comment: @KrisJones Can you please post the html or a link to the codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated question, it seems changing `$(this).parent()` to `$(this).parents('.parent')` inside the click handler for save or cancel button should solve this.

Answer (score 0):

use classes instead .css function that you can remove class when you click cancel or add more function if this has class